# Disabled textbox loses its values on page refresh in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I have a text box

```
        <input type="text" name="${field.formInputName}" 
           <c:if test="${maxLength ne -1}">maxlength="${maxLength}" </c:if>
           value="${textValue}" 
           <c:if test="${transferTask and lockField}">disabled</c:if> />
```

the first time page renders, the textbox has its value,
and the element appears like this

```
<input type="text" name="FLD_1007_1234" maxlength="255" 
   value="apparel" disabled="">
```

but if for some reason an error occurs like we did not fill some required values. the page refreshes, 
and all the data in the fields are lost only ones which are disabled.

```
<input type="text" name="FLD_1007_1234" maxlength="255" value="" disabled="">
```

the values are gone.

how can i solve this.?

Comment: Just to make sure, are all of these `${field.formInputName}`, `${maxLength}`, `${transferTask}, `${lockField}` and `${textValue}` set as request attributes or just `${textValue}` is page/request attribute while the others are session or servletcontext attributes?

Comment: request attribute-<c:set var="textValue" value="${datum.value}" /><c:set var="lockField" value="${taskCommand.Item.projectItem.lockField}" />
<c:set var="transferTask" value="${taskCommand.Item.transferNode}" />
<c:set var="field" value="${constraintDisplay.field }" scope="page"/>

Comment: And `${datum.value}` is request attribute or session attribute?

Comment: Turn off the cache control, it prevents the values comeback.

Comment: its request attribute.

Comment: it is the request attribute,and i want the values persist. if the field is not disabled, the values are always there when refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled controls are not submitted as part of the form. You should probably use a `readonly` control instead.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12 for the specification.